# Float left with wrap in Android

Tags: android

I'm interesting to get the same effect like in css `float: left` style. I'm using now `RelativeLayout` and `android:layout_toRightOf` but need views to goes to next line when they can't fit. How to achieve this in android layout ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="300dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/a"
        android:width="300dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b"
        android:width="300dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I need something like in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3zsz6yds/3/)

On wider screen i need to get **for example** 3 buttons in one line, but on smaller screen have to 2 buttons in one line and third in second line. Like in images below.

Smaller device

[image: smaller device]

Wider device

[image: wider device]

Comment: Will you please post what you have tried with the image?

Comment: do you want the buttons in the same line??

Comment: no. i need to buttons wrap to the next line if can't fit in one line

Comment: check my answer.is this what you require??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For single rows use a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation instead of a RelativeLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

<!-- add your views here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

For multiple rows you way want to automatically "flow" your elements to a new line. You can take a look at the [android flow-layout project](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) or try to implement your own according to [this custom implementation](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/android-horizontal-flow-layout.html)

```
/** Custom view which extends {@link RelativeLayout}
 * and which places its children horizontally,
 * flowing over to a new line whenever it runs out of width.*/
public class HorizontalFlowLayout
  extends RelativeLayout
{
  /** Constructor to use when creating View from code.*/
  public HorizontalFlowLayout(Context context)
  {
    super(context);
  }

  /** Constructor that is called when inflating View from XML.*/
  public HorizontalFlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  /** Perform inflation from XML and apply a class-specific base style.*/
  public HorizontalFlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
  {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
  {
    // need to call super.onMeasure(...) otherwise get some funny behaviour
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    // increment the x position as we progress through a line
    int xpos = getPaddingLeft();
    // increment the y position as we progress through the lines
    int ypos = getPaddingTop();
    // the height of the current line
    int line_height = 0;

    // go through children
    // to work out the height required for this view

    // call to measure size of children not needed I think?!
    // getting child's measured height/width seems to work okay without it
    //measureChildren(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    View child;
    MarginLayoutParams childMarginLayoutParams;
    int childWidth, childHeight, childMarginLeft, childMarginRight, childMarginTop, childMarginBottom;

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++)
    {
      child = getChildAt(i);

      if (child.getVisibility() != GONE)
      {
        childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();

        if (child.getLayoutParams() != null
            && child.getLayoutParams() instanceof MarginLayoutParams)
        {
          childMarginLayoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();

          childMarginLeft = childMarginLayoutParams.leftMargin;
          childMarginRight = childMarginLayoutParams.rightMargin;
          childMarginTop = childMarginLayoutParams.topMargin;
          childMarginBottom = childMarginLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
        }
        else
        {
          childMarginLeft = 0;
          childMarginRight = 0;
          childMarginTop = 0;
          childMarginBottom = 0;
        }

        if (xpos + childMarginLeft + childWidth + childMarginRight + getPaddingRight() > width)
        {
          // this child will need to go on a new line

          xpos = getPaddingLeft();
          ypos += line_height;

          line_height = childMarginTop + childHeight + childMarginBottom;
        }
        else
          // enough space for this child on the current line
          line_height = Math.max(
              line_height,
              childMarginTop + childHeight + childMarginBottom);

        xpos += childMarginLeft + childWidth + childMarginRight;
      }
    }

    ypos += line_height + getPaddingBottom();

    if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
      // set height as measured since there's no height restrictions
      height = ypos;
    else if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST
        && ypos < height)
      // set height as measured since it's less than the maximum allowed
      height = ypos;

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
  {
    // increment the x position as we progress through a line
    int xpos = getPaddingLeft();
    // increment the y position as we progress through the lines
    int ypos = getPaddingTop();
    // the height of the current line
    int line_height = 0;

    View child;
    MarginLayoutParams childMarginLayoutParams;
    int childWidth, childHeight, childMarginLeft, childMarginRight, childMarginTop, childMarginBottom;

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++)
    {
      child = getChildAt(i);

      if (child.getVisibility() != GONE)
      {
        childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();

        if (child.getLayoutParams() != null
            && child.getLayoutParams() instanceof MarginLayoutParams)
        {
          childMarginLayoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();

          childMarginLeft = childMarginLayoutParams.leftMargin;
          childMarginRight = childMarginLayoutParams.rightMargin;
          childMarginTop = childMarginLayoutParams.topMargin;
          childMarginBottom = childMarginLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
        }
        else
        {
          childMarginLeft = 0;
          childMarginRight = 0;
          childMarginTop = 0;
          childMarginBottom = 0;
        }

        if (xpos + childMarginLeft + childWidth + childMarginRight + getPaddingRight() > r - l)
        {
          // this child will need to go on a new line

          xpos = getPaddingLeft();
          ypos += line_height;

          line_height = childHeight + childMarginTop + childMarginBottom;
        }
        else
          // enough space for this child on the current line
          line_height = Math.max(
              line_height,
              childMarginTop + childHeight + childMarginBottom);

        child.layout(
            xpos + childMarginLeft,
            ypos + childMarginTop,
            xpos + childMarginLeft + childWidth,
            ypos + childMarginTop + childHeight);

        xpos += childMarginLeft + childWidth + childMarginRight;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When buttons have fixed width (in my example 300dp) they can't fit in smaller device and are "invisible". I need something different.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to mek your three buttons in 1 line for any **screen size device**.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want buttons have fixed width and dynamically wrap to next line if some not fit. In Your example have 3 buttons in one line **always**

Comment: Is button count dynamic or fixed??

Comment: The better would be dynamic, but for now it can be fixed, for example 3 buttons (with fixed width) like in my example